# Can anyone help me prove block diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices

If I have  Block matrix    A 0 
                           B C , where A,B,C are square matrices

I was trying to prove why determinant of this matrix is equal to product of determinant of A and C.

Can anyone help me?

Also, If I have A 0 
                0 I  ,where I is identity matrix, then determinant of this matrix is equal to A B
         0 I  for B is any square matrix?